# Can you help me analyze I-bVII-IV6-III?

Tags: chord-progressions

Playing around today I really liked the sound of C-Bb-F6-E as a four chord loop and I really don’t understand why. Maybe calling the third chord Dm7/F makes more sense? I think each transition is smooth and easy to voice lead but I can’t make sense of it otherwise. Am I missing something obvious in analysis? Can someone make more sense of this than I could?

Comment: Sometimes voice-leading trumps (straightforward) harmonic analysis... :)

Comment: Dm/F doesn't have a C in it. F6 does. Dm7/F and F6 each contain the same four pitches. Which are you referring to?

Comment: Also, your post suggests all of the chords are voiced in root position. If that's the case, please confirm; if not, please indicate the notes played in each chord from lowest to highest.

Comment: Good catch, Aaron, thanks. Edited to correct to Dm7/F. All chords are voiced in root position (unless we’re calling it Dm7/F rather than F6, in which case it’s in first inversion, I guess).

Comment: That helps. Thanks. And you experience the Bb to F6 transition as smooth?

Comment: Yes, although checking again both with and without the C in the third chord I do think it’s smoother without the C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C-Bb-F6 is a I-bVII-IV(-I) progression in C mixolydian (the 5th mode of major) a popular rock progression. As a logical consequence, Dm7/F doesn't seem like the correct spelling, especially since the D in F6 sounds more like a decoration/extension, likely because bVII-IV-I is a pattern of falling fourths.

I suppose E is taking the function of V/VIm (the dominant chord of VIm), but instead of resolving to VIm (Am), it resolves to its relative major, I (C), which turns out to work very pleasantly: the fifth of E (B) resolves up a semitone to the root of C (C), and the third of E (G#) resolves down a semitone to the fifth of C (G), thus giving E its dominant function due to the instability of the chord followed by a well-defined tonic.

Comment: A nice analysis, but I disagree technically about mixolydian. In jazz, blues, rock, and pop, pieces that use the b7 are still considered major.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron, not Mixolydian but major and the Bb is more of a borrowed chord from the parallel minor. A couple of indicators are pop melodies are more likely to use the ^M7 than the ^m7. Also pop tunes almost always use a iii not a iiio in their harmony. Otherwise, nice job, +1.